# element usage in html, flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm sending data into database by running this :

`INSERT INTO EVENT_DESC VALUES("Organized by ACM student chapter <br> Dept. of Computer Science and Engineering","");`

Taking from database and printing it happened without any errors.
I got line into html and printed it like this in **HTML** file:

`{{row['data']}}`

My output in **HTML** is:

`Organized by ACM student chapter <br> Dept. of Computer Science and Engineering`

But I want output as:

`Organized by ACM student chapter`

`Dept. of Computer Science and Engineering`

I think you guys understood, instead of going to new line it is priniting `<br>`.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

By default jinja2 (assuming you are using the template engine for flask) assumes input inside of `{{ }}` is unsafe and will not allow javascript or html inside them. You can solve this by using the `safe` filter inside your template. This will tell jinja2 that the content is safe to render as is, and not to escape the html/javascript.

```
{{ row['data'] | safe }}
```